# android, relationship between UI drawable and memory consuming

Tags: android, memory-management, user-interface

My app will consume 10M memory without the UI.  After adding UI to it, it will consume about 25M memory.  Sometimes this will produce crashing.  The image using as background, button, etc, was made in high quality by photoshop.  I want to know the relationship between the memory consuming and the image's quality and size.  For example:  the current background's resolution was 400x600, 60kb in disk, which one will reduce the memory using?

1. make its resolution smaller, like 40x60 and let it stretch.
2. reduce the quality to make this image file's size smaller, like 10kb.

I don't know if reducing the quality of an image file will affect the memory using.  If android will transfer the image to bitmap?  How to decide the size and resolution of the image resource.

Thank you.

Comment: To me it seems that the background image is not your real problem. See how big are the other images and try to reduce the depth. Also make sure you don't leak something since 10M without UI seems a lot (unless you keeping a lot of data in memory).

Comment: yes, I keep a lot of data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html. Start by reading the link

The above link gives you an idea of how to load bitmaps efficiently.
Try recycling the bitmap when not in use.

Use a MAT Analyzer to find memory leaks.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. The video in the links talks about memory management and how to find and get rid of memory leaks.

There might be other reasons for memory leaks. Reduce use of static variables (using static variables is not recommended). You, probably, should try to use Application Context and not the Activity context wherever possible (it's not always possible).

Without the code the community will not be able to find the actual cause of memory leaks.
[Performance tips to be considered.](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)